# Visual studio 2010 creates new project every time I open a web site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, web

I am working for a client who has a number of ASP.NET web sites (as opposed to ASP.NET web applications). Each time I open up one of these websites in VS2010 I have to tell Visual Studio to use IIS Express, and for older websites I have to tell VS2010 that I do not want to convert it to .NET 4.
I can see in the title bar, once the website has been loaded, that a new solution file is created each time, because it displays "[websitename] (NN)", and each time I load the web site NN increases by 1.
It would be handy if I could simply open up the solution file directly, or alternatively change a setting somewhere that tells VS2010 to use the existing solution file for this site.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Can't you just create an empty solution, add that website, and from then on open that solution rather than the website?

Comment: How would I add a site to a solution?

Comment: Right-click on solution (top in solution explorer), then Add..., then Existing Website..., then find your website.

Comment: OK ... I asked the wrong question ... how do you create an empty solution? I can create an empty project, which would presumably create a solution, then remove the project, then add the existing website, but that seems a bit convoluted. Is there not a way to open the solution that VS creates for me when I open a website? I guess I just need to find the default location for the solutions that are automatically created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps required to achieve that:

1. Add an empty solution by clicking File -> New -> Project -> Other project types -> Visual Studio Solutions
2. In your solution explorer which should show nothing except the one entry for your empty solution, right click on that solution entry, click Add -> Existing website, then find the existing website in your file system and confirm.

Done.